# react _this2.setState is not a function - possible binding issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I am super new to react, and I have been struggling to figure out what is causing this error in the `chrome console`

`bundle.js:15316 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this2.setState is not a function`

I am trying to do a simple login with facebook to a webapp, to learn the login flows.

I have setup my login on `/` (also my `home` page route). I don't think the problem is anywhere around routing or anything. This seems to be a problem with `binding` in `react` and being new to this framework - I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to solve this.

My `/` or `home` route `jsx` looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';


export default class Home extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { isAuthenticated: false, user: null, token: ''};
        this.setInputState = this.setInputState.bind(this);
    }

    /*logout = () => {
        this.setState({isAuthenticated: false, token: '', user: null})
    };*/

    responseFacebook(response) {
      console.log(response)
      const accessTokenBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({input_token: response.accessToken}, null, 2)], {type : 'application/json'});
      const options = {
          method: 'POST',
          body: accessTokenBlob,
          //mode: 'cors',
          cache: 'default'
      };
      fetch('http://localhost:8880/auth/facebook', options)
          .then((r) => r.json())
          .then(r => {
            console.log(r)
            if (r.status) {
                this.setState({isAuthenticated: true, user: response.id, token: response.accessToken})
            }
      });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        browserHistory.push('/');
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state)
        let content = this.state.isAuthenticated ?
        (
            <div>
                <p>Authenticated</p>
                <div>
                    {this.state.user.name}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.logout} className="button">
                        Log out
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div>
            <FacebookLogin
                appId="2128489194096154"
                autoLoad={true}
                fields="name,id,picture"
                scope="public_profile"
                callback={this.responseFacebook} />
            </div>
        );
        return (
            <div className="App">
                {content}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The **problem** seems to be happening on the line containing this section of the **code** `this.setState({isAuthenticated: true, user: response.id, token: response.accessToken})`

When I setup my `debug` on console on the browser, I am seeing this as the replaced content from the `this2` error stack link:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8880/auth/facebook', options).then(function (r) {
                return r.json();
            }).then(function (r) {
                console.log(r);
                if (r.status) {
                    _this2.setState({ isAuthenticated: true, user: response.id, token: response.accessToken });
                }
            });
```

I have been at this for almost a day now, and I am completely lost - have been reading a few articles - and have not gotten anywhere. As I keep trying to work through this, if the question is not clear - pls do let me know what more details i can add.

---

**EDIT #1**

`http://localhost:8880/auth/facebook` this is a backend which I have written, and this is something I control. The response log from the backend and the data received at frontend is the same. This tells me that there is no issues with `cors` or other integration issues.

Comment: Use arrow function like this `responseFacebook = (response) => {`

Comment: On line containing this `callback={this.responseFacebook} />` bind the responsefacebook function too.

Comment: thanks @PrakashSharma - your solution seems to have worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`responseFacebook` function is not bound to `class` context. So `this` inside `responseFacebook` function does not refer to the `class`. You can either use arrow function like this

```
responseFacebook = (response) => {
```

Or you can explicitly `bind` the function in `constructor` like this

```
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { isAuthenticated: false, user: null, token: ''};
        this.setInputState = this.setInputState.bind(this);
        this.responseFacebook = this.responseFacebook.bind(this);
    }
```

Comment: do you know why i would hit this error? with your first approach with `arrow function`? ```ERROR in ./src/components/views/home.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (23:21)

  21 |     };*/
  22 | 
> 23 |     responseFacebook = (response) => {
     |                      ^
```

Comment: your second approach worked for me, and I understood what the issue is and learnt the semantics better as well. Thanks for your help. But I am super curious why the arrow functions are not working for me, any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @sudhishkr It shows syntax error. Are you sure your syntax is correct? Could you show the code after changing it to arrow function?

Comment: codeshare link : https://codeshare.io/50P18N (this expires in 24hrs - as i did not want to modify my question)

Comment: I think its mostly because of some missing `babel` spec in the `package.json`

Comment: cool no worries, I’ll continue digging on that front. You solved my problem .. thanks for your help. Choosing your answer for this question